# module github.com/astaxie/beego@latest found (v1.12.3), but does not contain package github.com/astaxie/beego/client/orm

Tags: beego

I get this error when I try to execute `bee migrate`, do anyone get the same error? how to handle it? thank you

```
2020/11/06 03:54:37 INFO     ▶ 0001 Getting bee latest version...
2020/11/06 03:54:37 WARN     ▶ 0002 Update available 2.0.0 ==> 1.12.0
2020/11/06 03:54:37 WARN     ▶ 0003 Run `bee update` to update
2020/11/06 03:54:37 INFO     ▶ 0004 Your bee are up to date
______
| ___ \
| |_/ /  ___   ___
| ___ \ / _ \ / _ \
| |_/ /|  __/|  __/
\____/  \___| \___| v2.0.0
2020/11/06 03:54:37 INFO     ▶ 0005 Using 'postgres' as 'driver'
2020/11/06 03:54:37 INFO     ▶ 0006 Using '/go/src/chatcommerce-api/database/migrations' as 'dir'
2020/11/06 03:54:37 INFO     ▶ 0007 Running all outstanding migrations
2020/11/06 03:54:37 INFO     ▶ 0008 Creating 'migrations' table...
2020/11/06 03:54:38 ERROR    ▶ 0009 Could not build migration binary: exit status 1
2020/11/06 03:54:38 ERROR    ▶ 0010 |> go: finding module for package github.com/astaxie/beego/client/orm
2020/11/06 03:54:38 ERROR    ▶ 0011 |> go: finding module for package github.com/astaxie/beego/client/orm/migration
2020/11/06 03:54:38 ERROR    ▶ 0012 |> m.go:6:2: module github.com/astaxie/beego@latest found (v1.12.3), but does not contain package github.com/astaxie/beego/client/orm
2020/11/06 03:54:38 ERROR    ▶ 0013 |> m.go:7:2: module github.com/astaxie/beego@latest found (v1.12.3), but does not contain package github.com/astaxie/beego/client/orm/migration
2020/11/06 03:54:38 WARN     ▶ 0014 Could not remove temporary file: remove m: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/astaxie/beego/issues/4308

go get -u github.com/astaxie/beego@develop
go get github.com/beego/bee@v1.12.3

Comment: I don't see a question here